# MySQL double/decimal return too many decimals

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have in my database 2 columns one is decimal and one is double. They are set as 10,6.
For testing purposes, I set values as: 45.554962. When I get data from database on my server it returns: 45.55536200000000235377228818833827972412109375

Not even PHP round() function changes that. I can't find a solution to it. I'm using Laravel, PHP 7 and MySQL 5.6

Comment: *They are set as 10,6* - only the decimal one is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use truncate

```
 TRUNCATE(your_column, 2)
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate

Comment: Problem is that I'm modifying the original value ( 45.554962) and then sending it to output and PHP still returns big number with a lot of decimals